# How do I pass JSON from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to get data from a database with PHP and passing it to jQuery so I can use it in a dynamic google chart. I have converted my PHP array to JSON with json_encode() but now I have to access this data with jQuery to pass it to the google chart.

My PHP code:

```
$db = new Db(DB_NAME, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$dates = array();
for($number=14; $number>=1; $number--) {
    $dateValue = date('j M', strtotime("-$number day"));
    $getCount[$number] = $db->get($this->styleName, $dateValue);
    $items[$dateValue[$number]] = $getCount[$number];
}
$json_encode = json_encode($dates);
var_dump($json_encode);
```

My outputted JSON:

```
{
"15 Apr": "19",
"16 Apr": "15",
"17 Apr": "18",
"18 Apr": "13",
"19 Apr": "27",
"20 Apr": "2",
"21 Apr": "12",
"22 Apr": "9",
"23 Apr": "11",
"24 Apr": "20",
"25 Apr": "25",
"26 Apr": "137",
"27 Apr": "99",
"28 Apr": "115"
}
```

My main question is how do I pass this data to my jQuery script?
Can someone say me if I am doing this the right way or help me to get on the right track?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See $.getJSON() here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
Just echo your `json_encode($dates);`

Comment: Use echo and EXIT() after it (so no other code is send later)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send json header at the beginning of your php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// build $datas
echo json_encode($datas);
?>
```

And pull the json with jquerys getJSON function:

```
$.getJSON('path/to/php/file.php', function(jsondata) {
    // use jsondata here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it in a seperate request, so your request only output the json and fetch it with $.getJson(); It is a clean way but requires an extra request;

or you can include it in  tags in the html

output template:

```
<html>
  ...
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.yourOwnJqueryExtention.setJSON(<?=$myJSON?>); 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

much simpler, you don't need to change header info(this is hardly possible in Wordpress for example), just convert encoded object to string.

```
$json_encode = (string)$json_encode;
```

Comment: This doesn't actually show the OP how to pass the JSON data to jQuery.